# Do noun phrases comprise prepositions too?

Tags: british-english, noun-phrases

Do noun phrases comprise prepositions too? 
For example:

> The apple in the fridge is mine.

Here the noun phrase is "The apple in the fridge" or just "The apple"?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly -- it would depend on what you mean by "comprise". In your example, "in the fridge" is not a constituent of the noun phrase "the apple in the fridge", but rather modifies "apple".  The constituent structure is: [NP the [ apple [PP in [NP the fridge ] ] ] ].

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "in the fridge" is part of the noun phrase in your example because it's dependent on "apple" in this case it's describing it.